# Tem como colocar um spinner em função a outra spinner só como imagem?

Tags: android-studio

Sou novato no Android Studio e queria fazer dois spinners. Um que estaria por exemplo carros,motos e quando selecionada a opção o outro aparecesse as imagens com os nomes dos carros ( caso selecionada carros ) ou motos ( caso selecionado motos)

Comment: Pergunta respondida. O foco do site é esclarecer dúvidas referentes principalmente a erros. Quando você estiver fazendo e estiver em dúvidas coloque o código que você fez e o erro que apresenta e mais pessoas irão te ajudar :D

Answer (score 1):

Primeira situação - preencher o segundo spinner após a seleção da informação no primeiro:
Para isso você pode utilizar o [OnItemSelectedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html). Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        //seu código aqui }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        //seu código aqui  }

});
```

Segunda situação - fazer o spinner aparecer imagens:
Você precisará, para isso, fazer um layout customizado para o seu spinner. Tem um tutorial disso nesse link para facilitar para você: https://www.codingdemos.com/android-custom-spinner-images-text/